# Использование SQLXML в .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server

Установил SqlXml 4.0 Service Pack 1 (SP1), в References проекта добавил `%PROGRAMFILES%\SQLXML 4.0\bin\Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.dll`

Пытаюсь получить данные так

```
string s = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=(localdb)\\MS;database=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI";
SqlXmlCommand c = SqlXmlCommand(s);
c.CommandText = "select * from tbl";
SqlXmlAdapter a = SqlXmlAdapter(c);
DataSet d = new DataSet();
a.Fill(d);
```

Получаю ошибку

> Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.SqlXmlException: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Хотя SQL Server работает нормально и можно подключиться через SqlConnection.

Comment: Возможно проблема в авторизации, или имени сервера. `SQL Server does not exist or access denied.` явно говорит о том что SQL Server к которому вы подключаетесь не найден или доступа к нему нет

Comment: Сервер работает нормально, а при `Integrated Security=SSPI` используются логин Windows. Код выполняется из визуал студии в режиме админ. Непонятно почему ошибка, если с тем же логином я открываю базу в Sql Server Managment Studio.